# Using HTML.PHP instead of html.twig - not working

Tags: php, html, symfony, model-view-controller, twig

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($page, $name) {
        return $this->render('default/new.html.php'
        //         , array(
        //     $name => 'bob'
        // )
        );
    }
}
```

**new.html.php**

```
<p>Welcome to the index <?= $name; ?></p>
```

When I use this code it is returning an error message.

But,

```
<p>Welcome to the index {{ name }}
```

this returns me correct output.

I want to use `.html.php` instead of `.html.twig`

I am going through this https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating/PHP.html

**routing.yml**

```
app:
    path:      /dd
    defaults:
        _controller: AppBundle:Default:index
        page:        1
        name:       "bob"
```

**config.yml**

```
framework:
    # ...
    templating:
        engines: ['twig', 'php']
```

Note: I am using ubuntu16.04 and Symfony 3.4

Comment: What is error message?

Comment: Controller "AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$name" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one.

Comment: You pass parameter to action, but you  didn't define it in route.
https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/routing/extra_information.html

Comment: Now I get the output but "name" is still not displayed - my output is "Welcome to the index"

Comment: Did you configure your `Symfony` to make it use `PHP` templates? See [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/PHP.html)

Comment: @DarkBee S, I configured already. is there anything that I must do after making changes in "config.yml" ???

Comment: Pass array("name" => "Bob") like this.

Comment: @Zamir10 Tried... no change...am trying to echo the $name variable.. for that what must I do?

Comment: Please update your question with changes

Comment: @Zamir10 I have updated the code with changes.

Comment: change path like this: /path/{page}/{name}

Comment: Still not displayed.. when I apply the parameter as "/1/bob" the url is working without error but it is not displayed in HTML

Comment: You still need to pass the variable like `$this->render('template.php', [ 'name' => $name, ]);` and then access it with `<?= $name; ?>` though. In your (commented) example code you are just creating a variable `bob` which contains `bob` `(<?= $bob; ?>, output bob)`

Comment: @DarkBee getting a blank page

Comment: Any errors? View your server log.

Comment: @D.Dimitrov while looking into inspect, I can see it commented like this <!-- ? =$name; ?-->

Comment: I've tried locally on my symfony, and it's working like a charm. Maybe you've missed something..

Comment: @D.Dimitrov  can u post your code as an answer here...

Comment: @newbie https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279901/php-gets-commented-out-in-html maybe short php tags are not supported?

Comment: @Vyctorya I checked it.iam using html.php extension. And if i type outside the php tag then it is displayed in the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried locally according to Symfony documentation:

```
/**
 * @Route("/test", name="test_route")
 */
public function test()
{
    return $this->render(
        'test.html.php',
        [
            'test_var' => 'Hello test',
        ]
    );
}
```

My `test.html.php`:

```
<?php
echo $test_var;
```

This outputs `Hello test`.

PS: Tried `get_defined_vars();`, the variable should be seen there.

Comment: Tried ...still blank output...will it be an issue in php server in ubuntu??

Comment: It could be configuration issue. What does `var_dump(get_defined_vars());` outputs?

Comment: maybe the problem will be with my configuration...will check it..problem seems to be in php..because php content is not accepted in _new.html.php_ still, that page returns a blank output.. if I write something **out of php tag** then it is displayed in new.html.php

Comment: I tried it in **windows** too..but no change...do I want to change anything in __routing.yml__

Comment: Are you using annotations to route? If so - no.

Comment: Initially, I tried with annotations..then now without annotations...please check my code

Comment: @ D. Dimitrov I tried without annotations too..but why I must try without annotations...