# Apache - How can I run a PHP script when opening HTML files?

Tags: php, html, apache

## Background

I am working on a website, which runs on an Apache server on Windows (at least at the moment). My website directories consist of HTML and PHP files. The idea is to have accessible webpages as HTML files, and whenever I need to use dynamic content, I will use Javascript and AJAX requests in order to request what I need from the server. AJAX requests will be made to PHP scripts, which have a directory dedicated to them. Because I would like to keep everything well organised in their own units, this is the way I do it (I try to avoid inline PHP as much as possible).

## Objective

Public HTML files do not need any special settings. When it comes to administrator specific HTML files, however, I would like to do something very specific with them. Instead of writing some inline PHP code to authenticate a user as an administrator on an administrator webpage (an HTML file), I would like to execute authentication script whenever a user tries to open administrator specific HTML files, to check, if the user can open the file.

## Question

In short, this is my question: *how can I run a PHP script when opening HTML files?* What kind of configurations do I need to do on the Apache server or can I simply utilize PHP somehow?

Comment: How about creating common parts of page in html and loading administrative tools using ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you serve static HTML files, you cannot prevent a user to access it without using a programming language like PHP (or e.g. `.htaccess`). There are however multiple ways to handle your situation:

1. You could fetch all administrative data from the PHP scripts with AJAX. This means that all your users could theoretically see how your administration is built of (the whole HTML structure without relevant data). Of course, you can create a redirect, if the AJAX call fails, but you are still offering the whole HTML of the administration.
2. You can store your administration HTML file in the back-end. The user then tries to access the administration and the only thing he gets, is an AJAX call to the back-end. If the call is successful, the HTML is delivered with AJAX to the front-end. This prevents the users to see your administration HTML.
3. You can use a small PHP snippet on top of every administration page which checks if a user should have access to this page. This prevents the users also to see your administration HTML.
4. You store the HTML of your administration in an HTML file, also served to the user. Then, you make an initial call to the back-end on page load. In the success case, you make another AJAX call to fetch the administartion HTML. The user could potentially see the administration HTML (if he directly opens the file).
5. You could use a PHP independent server authentication with `.htaccess`. `.htaccess` is an apache server authentication configuration file. You can use it to prevent a user from accessing your site (so, there is no access to the HTML file at all). When trying to access the page, a popup appears and the user has to enter his credentials. It is completely independent from your business logic and the allowed users have to be set in a `.htpasswd` text file. There is no way to use a modern database-relying user management with `.htaccess` server authentication. With this solution, you also cannot use an HTML form to log in. I would only recommend this solution for testing purposes and not for a modern website.

If your PHP back-end is solidly built, I would go for solution `1`. The user cannot do anything with your HTML, if you are properly checking the user's input on your back-end interface. This means, you serve all the HTML, but do not display it to the user until the data is loaded. You can show a [spinner](http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/) while it is loading. Here is some basic code:

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'administration.php',
        method: 'GET'
        success: function(response) {
            $('input.username').val(response.username);
            // ( ... )
            $('.administration').fadeIn('fast');
        },
        error: function() {
            window.location.href = 'index.php';
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="administration">
        <label>Username 
            <input type="text" class="username" />
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.administration {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Accepted this answer, because is the most complete this far. It is a good thing you provided a lot of different options. I like the option #1, too. I must think about the implementation of that, if it is feasible. ;)

Comment: @HenriKorpela Thanks! Just as an additional information: To separate the front-end and back-end, I would go for a REST interface. This provides a clean interface between the data of the back-end and your JavaScript front-end. You can then request all the data with AJAX requests. The benefit of REST is the multiple endpoints for any resource: If you have e.g. `localhost/api/account` you can make a HTTP GET request to retrieve the account, POST for creating a new account, PUT for updating and HTTP DELETE for deleting the account. This keeps a clean separation between PHP and HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with an `iframe` / `embed` tag,

OR:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'php_File_with_php_code.php',
                type: 'GET', 
                data: 'parameter=some_parameter',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#thisdiv').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="thisdiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Source: [How to run a php script inside a html file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853669/how-to-run-a-php-script-inside-a-html-file)

Comment: ssc-hrep3's answer is probably the most complete, but this will at least point into a good direction. Thanks, I will keep this solution in mind. :)

Comment: You're welcome! Now I know how to accomplish this on my future projects too :)

Answer (score 0):

You may simply configure your Server (APACHE) to treat Files with .html extension as regular PHP Files.
Here is how: if you don't have a .htaccess File in your Project root, create it.
Then inside the .htaccess File add the following line:

```
    # TELLS APACHE TO HANDLE ALL FILES WITH .html or .htm EXTENSIONS AS PHP FILES.
    AddHandler x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

However, depending on your Server, the above may not work; in which case you may may try one of the following:

```
    # TELLS APACHE TO HANDLE ALL FILES WITH .html or .htm EXTENSIONS AS PHP FILES.
    AddHandler php-script .php .html .htm
```

or this:

```
    # TELLS APACHE TO HANDLE ALL FILES WITH .html or .htm EXTENSIONS AS PHP FILES.
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

However, the first variant may most likely work for you. I hope this helps. Good Luck to you, my Friend.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but unfortunately this answer does not answer the question. The intention was not to run HTML files like PHP files, but run a PHP script each time user opens an HTML file in a specified directory.