# PHP not working in Firefox on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: php, html

In firefox I repeatedly tried to get PHP working, but no luck

My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>

            <h1>My first PHP page</h1>

            <?php
                echo "Hello World!";
            ?>

        </body>
    </html>
```

I used PHP format, but it wanted to save the script *again*.
XML threw a **boatload** of *errors*.
HTML did ***not*** show the PHP

Comment: this all depends on your webserver and php settings. Check this reply:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853669/how-can-i-run-a-php-script-inside-a-html-file

Comment: PHP runs on the server, not the client. The browser shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: What are the errors you saw?

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to use PHP without a web server. As PHP runs on the server side, this is not possible. There are many web servers compatible with PHP, but for a beginner, I would recommend XAMPP, a bundle of programs to help you get started.

Comment: @CoderCharmander I have a web server on my client, but I cannot modify it

Comment: @Velcro "A web server on my client" doesn't make sense; it's like saying "outside on the inside". And what does "cannot modify it" mean? If it's a case of not having permission to run something, that's not something we can help with, you need to ask whoever can give you that permission. Just loading the PHP in a browser is never going to work.